# Python os.sendfile raises OSError: [Errno 38] Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: python, python-os

I am learning python `os` module and faced the issue with `os.sendfile(...)` method. Here's my code

```py
import os
f1 = os.open('f1.txt', os.O_RDONLY)
f2 = os.open('f2.txt', os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT)
os.sendfile(f2, f1, 0, 100) # <-- Raises OSError: [Errno 38] Socket operation on non-socket
os.close(f1)
os.close(f2)
```

Python version: 3.9.6
OS: macos monterey (12.6.1)

Here's the link with article that I am trying to follow: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-sendfile-method/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the whole [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) is basically just a wrapper for the underlying operation system API. So while the python docs for [os.sendfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sendfile) don't mention anything that would explain your observation, the man page [sendfile(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sendfile.2.html) does:

> The sendfile() system call sends a regular file specified by descriptor fd out a **stream socket** specified by descriptor s.

(emphasis added by me)

So on MacOS (Darwin), sendfile can only be used to send data to a stream socket, not to an arbitrary file descriptor. This is different to Linux, where you *can* send data to an arbitrary file descriptor. Which may be the reason this isn't mentioned in the python docs.